# Rewrite Github Author/Commit History

Tags: git, github

I previously did not have my username and email properly configured in my dev enviornment so my commits did not have that info and in my contributions graph none of those commits appear. I have fixed this to work for future use. I am trying to use the script provided by github to fix the prior commits but am not having success, below I have pasted the script as I am using it. What is it I am doing incorrectly?

```bash
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch -f --env-filter '

an="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
am="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
cn="$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME"
cm="$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "myemail@gmail.com" ]
then
    cn="justinrsmith"
    cm="justinrsmith88@gmail.com"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "myemail@gmail.com" ]
then
    an="justinrsmith"
    am="justinrsmith88@gmail.com"
fi

export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$an"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$am"
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$cn"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$cm"
'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this, had to do a `git push -f origin`.